# Spark: Match columns from two dataframes

Tags: apache-spark, dataframe, apache-spark-sql

I have a dataframe of format as below

```
+---+---+------+---+
| sp|sp2|colour|sp3|
+---+---+------+---+
|  0|  1|     1|  0|
|  1|  0|     0|  1|
|  0|  0|     1|  0|
+---+---+------+---+
```

another dataframe contains coefficients for each column in first dataframe. for example

```
+------+------+---------+------+
| CE_sp|CE_sp2|CE_colour|CE_sp3|
+------+------+---------+------+
|  0.94|  0.31|     0.11|  0.72|
+------+------+---------+------+
```

Now I want to add a column to first dataframe which is calculated by adding scores from second dataframe.

for ex.

```
+---+---+------+---+-----+
| sp|sp2|colour|sp3|Score|
+---+---+------+---+-----+
|  0|  1|     1|  0| 0.42|
|  1|  0|     0|  1| 1.66|
|  0|  0|     1|  0| 0.11|
+---+---+------+---+-----+
```

i.e

```
r -> row of first dataframe
score = r(0)*CE_sp + r(1)*CE_sp2 + r(2)*CE_colour + r(3)*CE_sp3
```

There can be n number of columns and order of columns can be different.

Thanks in Advance!!!

Comment: so your second DataFrame contains actually 1 row with 4 values ?

Comment: @eliasah values can increase but no of rows will always remain 1 in second dataframe.

Comment: The you don't actually need a second DataFrame

Comment: @eliasah Sure. Please close it

Comment: can you check the same with all your other questions please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Quick and simple:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.col

val df = Seq(
  (0, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0)
).toDF("sp","sp2", "colour", "sp3")

val coefs = Map("sp" -> 0.94, "sp2" -> 0.32, "colour" -> 0.11, "sp3" -> 0.72)
val score = df.columns.map(
  c => col(c) * coefs.getOrElse(c, 0.0)).reduce(_ + _)

df.withColumn("score", score)
```

And the same thing in PySpark:

```py
from pyspark.sql.functions import col

df = sc.parallelize([
    (0, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0)
]).toDF(["sp","sp2", "colour", "sp3"])

coefs = {"sp": 0.94, "sp2": 0.32, "colour": 0.11, "sp3": 0.72}
df.withColumn("score", sum(col(c) * coefs.get(c, 0) for c in df.columns))
```

Comment: Thanks it serves the purpose

Answer (score 1):

I believe that there many way to accomplish what you are trying to do. In all cases you don't need that second DataFrame, like I said in the comments.

Here is one way :

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.{ElementwiseProduct, VectorAssembler}
import org.apache.spark.mllib.linalg.{Vectors,Vector => MLVector}

val df = Seq((0, 1, 1, 0), (1, 0, 0, 1), (0, 0, 1, 0)).toDF("sp", "sp2", "colour", "sp3")

// Your coefficient represents a dense Vector
val coeffSp = 0.94
val coeffSp2 = 0.31
val coeffColour = 0.11
val coeffSp3 = 0.72

val weightVectors = Vectors.dense(Array(coeffSp, coeffSp2, coeffColour, coeffSp3))

// You can assemble the features with VectorAssembler
val assembler = new VectorAssembler()
  .setInputCols(df.columns) // since you need to compute on all your columns
  .setOutputCol("features")

// Once these features assembled we can perform an element wise product with the weight vector
val output = assembler.transform(df)
val transformer = new ElementwiseProduct()
  .setScalingVec(weightVectors)
  .setInputCol("features")
  .setOutputCol("weightedFeatures")

// Create an UDF to sum the weighted vectors values
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.udf
def score = udf((score: MLVector) => { score.toDense.toArray.sum })

// Apply the UDF on the weightedFeatures
val scores = transformer.transform(output).withColumn("score",score('weightedFeatures))
scores.show
// +---+---+------+---+-----------------+-------------------+-----+
// | sp|sp2|colour|sp3|         features|   weightedFeatures|score|
// +---+---+------+---+-----------------+-------------------+-----+
// |  0|  1|     1|  0|[0.0,1.0,1.0,0.0]|[0.0,0.31,0.11,0.0]| 0.42|
// |  1|  0|     0|  1|[1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0]|[0.94,0.0,0.0,0.72]| 1.66|
// |  0|  0|     1|  0|    (4,[2],[1.0])|     (4,[2],[0.11])| 0.11|
// +---+---+------+---+-----------------+-------------------+-----+
```

I hope this helps. Don't hesitate if you have more questions.

Comment: Hi. In the line ".setInputCols(df.columns) // since you need to compute on all your columns", is it possible to select only some columns instead of all?

Comment: I'm not sure I get your question.

Comment: I have a df with string and int columns. I want to add a column for weighted  features of all the int columns. In the above case, all the columns (sp, sp2, colour, sp3) are used to calculate weights. In my case, I want to select only a few columns to calculate the weight column. Is this possible? I tried something like this     val fields:Array[String] = Array("sAtt1","sAtt2","sAtt3","sAtt4","sAtt5","sAtt6","sAtt7","sAtt8","sAtt9","sAtt10")    val assembler = new VectorAssembler().setInputCols(fields).setOutputCol("features")

Comment: Normally yes you can. In this case, we needed all columns.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a simple solution:

```
scala> df_wght.show
+-----+------+---------+------+
|ce_sp|ce_sp2|ce_colour|ce_sp3|
+-----+------+---------+------+
|    1|     2|        3|     4|
+-----+------+---------+------+

scala> df.show
+---+---+------+---+
| sp|sp2|colour|sp3|
+---+---+------+---+
|  0|  1|     1|  0|
|  1|  0|     0|  1|
|  0|  0|     1|  0|
+---+---+------+---+
```

Then we can just do a simple cross join and crossproduct.

```
val scored = df.join(df_wght).selectExpr("(sp*ce_sp + sp2*ce_sp2 + colour*ce_colour + sp3*ce_sp3) as final_score")
```

The output:

```
scala> scored.show
+-----------+                                                                   
|final_score|
+-----------+
|          5|
|          5|
|          3|
+-----------+
```